# JVM heap size zookeeper

Tags: jvm, cassandra, apache-zookeeper

I have Zookeeper and Cassandra both running on the same machine. I have 8GB heap size allocated to Cassandra. I dont have any settings for my Zookeeper heap size, by default it would take 2GB(64-bit machine,16GB RAM). Is there any preferred heap size setting for Zookeeper(its not overloaded with znodes). Is there any way I can figure out the current heap size for zookeeper( can I use JConsole?).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We are running a similar configuration of zookeeper and Cassandra sharing a machine.  In deciding how to split the machine's resources you need to think about the load that will be applied to each server.  In our case we are making heavy use of Cassandra and light use of Zookeeper..and our resource allocation reflects that.

We also try to leave as much ram as possible for file system caching (we're running on Ubuntu).  So, your configuration actually looks fine (without knowing your usage patterns).

For finding the memory usage you have several options: top, jstat and as you suggest JConsole.  JConsole is probably the best as it lets you view not only your current usage but also your GC behavior (which is really what you want to check).